# Webview in recyclerview does not expand in place. (Not scaling down at the bottom)

Tags: android, html, android-webview, android-recyclerview

I'm working on something similar to 'Inbox by google' which needs me to have multiple webviews inside a recyclerView where I can expand and collapse the contents by tapping on the header which would add/remove the webview under the header.

Here is a gist of the project so far

```
Fragment
 -> RecyclerView (match_parent on height and width)
   -> Adapter + ViewModel/Model
     -> XML + Databinding.
```

XML Structure

```
LinearLayout (vertical)
 -> Header (match_parent on width, wrap_content on height)
 -> WebView (match_parent on width, wrap_content on height) 
(Webview does not scroll and it scales with the contents.
 the recyler view handles scrolling)
```

By default, all the webviews are made visibility gone and when the user clicks on the header for the first time the webview.loadDataWithBaseUrl() is called with the contents it is supposed to load and turns the visibility on. the webview scales its height to show the content fully. when the user clicks on the header again, it turns the visibility to gone and the whole row is collapsed to just the header. Clicking on the header again which was previously expanded, I don't have to load the data again and I just turn the visibility on.

everything works great mostly but for this one very annoying issue. 
https://nofile.io/f/UBCh5PO7Wv9/screencapture-1525973579493.mp4 this a recording from inbox by Google and my app has the exact same problem.

when I tap on the header to expand and the contents load in the webview, some webviews expand below and by that I mean the header stays put and it looks like the contents are loading below the clicked header.

but for certain content the webviews expand up, meaning it pushes the header which was clicked on to expand the contents, up. Which means I'm looking at the end of the contents than the top. like in this case of the inbox, I'm looking at the end of the email but not at the top of the email.

I copied the sources of the email in the video I shared and used them to load in my webviews and here are my findings.

- it has nothing to do with the contents loaded because even I jumble things up it happens
- it has nothing to do with the count of the webviews or the index of a given webview either
- it doesn't happen if I expand the contents from top to bottom. meaning from index 0..n
  -> BUT BUT BUT it always happens when I have everything collapsed and I expand contents from bottom to top.. from n to 0.

[image]

basically, if A and B are the top and bottom edges of the webview, ideally A should stay stable and B should increase down pushing the recyclerView contents below it. but instead, when I expand the contents from bottom up, the bottom line B stays stable and the webview increases up and pushes the header and the items above the given row along with it which is causing an annoying behavior of looking at the end of the contents than the top like in the inbox by google as well.

Here is a gif of whats happening 
- when I tap on a violet header, the webview(pink) loads the email. when I tap on the last one, the webview expands below. But when I tap on the 2nd last one it expands above which pushes the header up as well.

[image]

any thoughts? help?

thanks

Comment: I would recommend to upload your video to youtube or better post a gif here.

Comment: i did add a link the desc to the same problem in inbox by google. 
i now added a gif of the problem as well @azizbekian

Answer (score 0):

Call [scrollToPosition](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/LinearLayoutManager.html#scrollToPosition(int)) or [scrollToPositionWithOffset](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/LinearLayoutManager.html#scrollToPositionWithOffset(int,%20int)) after making the webview visible to force the recycler view to scroll to the beginning of the child view, your header in that case.

Comment: thanks @TpoM6oH. i didnt wanna call any of the scroll apis. that will cause a jump in the UI. like in the demo gif, if i add a scroll api, it would move the header as well to the top of the device. this means the header which the user clicked on has moved up. I want that to be in the same position like expanding the last email in the gif where the webview expands below the header unlike the 2nd last.

Answer (score 0):

This is how android system handles your view. For better UX you should put your selected(expanded) view on top of list in recyclerView. For achieving this you should handle items onClick listener inside of your adapter and then return position of item and use

```
scrollToPositionWithOffset(pos, 0);
```

Like this:

```
LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new NullDeividerItemDecoration());
MyAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter<>(context, list, new
           OnAdapterItemClickListener<WebsiteDto>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAdapterItemClick(WebsiteDto websiteDto , int pos) {
                        //Scroll item pos to 0 pixels from the top
                        linearLayoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(pos, 0);
                    }


                    @Override
                    public void onAdapterItemLongClick(WebsiteDto websiteDto) {

                    }
                });

recyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
```

Hope helpful.

Comment: thanks @Kenji. We are trying out some animations. so i dont want the views to move. The views are swaped when expanded from collapsed. but since there are some views like Avatar which are common, im trying out some shared element transitions like effects. but they wont work if i move the view to the top of the email. So im just interested in keeping the views from moving around like this.

Comment: @onusopus ok, check this out. may helps: https://github.com/wasabeef/recyclerview-animators
Check how this lib handled animations.